# All button state chnages instead of one button on onclick

Tags: reactjs

I want to change text of only clicked button, like when I'm making shopping cart and I click on "add to cart" button so it should change to *"added to cart"*.

But in my case all buttons text changes to *"added to cart"* on clicked button. This is because I'm sharing common state for all buttons. But I dont know how to do.

Also, when I refresh my page it again shows "add to cart" text on button. Instead of using redux is there any way to handle this?

```
addToCart(image, name, type, price, id) {
    const found = this.state.selectedProduct.some(el => el.id === id);
    const obj = {
        image,
        name,
        type,
        price,
        id
    };

    const selectedProduct = found ? this.state.selectedProduct : [...this.state.selectedProduct, obj];
    const totalPrice = found ? this.state.totalPrice : this.state.totalPrice + parseInt(price, 10)

    this.setState({
        selectedProduct,
        totalPrice,
        isAdded: true
    })

    localStorage.setItem('total', totalPrice);
    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(selectedProduct));
}



   <button
    key={i}
    id={i}       
    style={{backgroundColor:'#f15d24',cursor:"pointer",fontSize:'small',padding:'10px', border:'none', color:'white',float:'right', borderRadius:'5px', fontWeight:'bold'}}
    type="button"
    onClick={this.addToCart.bind(
             this,
             publicUrl+item.icon,
             item.title,
             item.type,
             ele.offer,
             i
   )}
                                   
>
  {this.state.isAdded ? "Added to Cart" : "Add To Cart"}</button>
```

[After clicking on first item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jzF5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.state.isAdded` is attached to every unique item so one change in any one item leads to change for all items

make `isAdded` an object of the key as items id and value as boolean

```
// in state initialisation

isAdded: {}

// in render()

{this.state.isAdded && this.state.isAdded[i] ? "Added to Cart" : "Add To Cart"}

// in addToCart()

const isAdded = this.state.isAdded;

isAdded[id] = true;

this.setState({
  selectedProduct,
  totalPrice,
  isAdded,
})
```

Comment: yes it works! But if i refresh it again goes to "add to cart".So can you help me with this?

Comment: this is happening because now you are not persisting the status in any database yet